# Get AtTask SessionID when SSO enabled?

Tags: web-services, saml, attask

I am trying to get a "SessionID" from an external system for AtTask using a web service call:

https://mycompanyname.attask-ondemand.com/attask/api/login?username=XXXXXX&password=YYYYYY

SSO with SAML is enabled and I get the following error:

"Sorry, you can't access AtTask through this login screen. AtTask is set up for Federated Single Sign-On with SAML 2.0. Please contact your system administrator."

I want to use a dedicated account that exists only in AtTask (not one from our Active Directory).  Does anyone know a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have found the solution, in the AtTask setup screen there is an option bypass SSO for a particular user.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a REST API call to login? Do you get the same error. http://developers.attask.com/api-docs/#Login

Comment: Yes, it is the REST API I was using (URI in the original question).